# Seeing all classes that extent current viewed class in javadocs?

Tags: java, javadoc

At the risk of sounding incredibly stupid and receiving a rather patronising answer, how do I view all other classes that extend the current 'viewed class' in javadocS?

i.e.

```
Object a {}

Object b extends a {}
```

Viewing a, is there a way to see 'all classes that have extended this class A'... therefore showing 'Class B'.

EDIT:

Thanks for that. There is an API I am reading at the minute where I was *certain* there had to be subclasses... turns out it doesn't! Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc should automatically generate the "Direct known subclasses" section, which in this case would list class B.

You shouldn't need to do anything to make this show up, so if you're not, there's a possibility it's a bug in the javadoc generator (however, unless you've presented a simplified version here, I'd be surprised if this trivial case triggers it).

Answer (score 1):

Outside of your IDE javadocs in browser have a header "Direct Known Subclasses:" like the one in the javadoc for [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). In IntelliJ IDEA all implementations/extensions of currently viewed interface/class can be seen if you press  + B.